# Getting error when updating two table in my sql

Tags: sql, oracle

when i am trying to update two table using below syntax i am getting below error:

> Error starting at line 20 in command:

```
UPDATE 
     tableA t1, 
     tableAClone t2
SET 
      t1.SECTION_ID = t2.SECTION_ID 
WHERE
     t1.CATEGORY_id = t2.CATEGORY_id
```

> Error at Command Line:21 Column:30
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
>   00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

```
UPDATE 
     tableA t1, 
     tableAClone t2
SET 
      t1.SECTION_ID = t2.SECTION_ID 
WHERE
     t1.CATEGORY_id = t2.CATEGORY_id;
```

Comment: You cannot update several tables in one sql statement

Answer (score 2):

Your sintax is not valid in oracle try using

```
    UPDATE tableA 
      SET tableA.SECTION_ID = (
            SELECT tableAClone.SECTION_ID
            FROM tableAClone 
            WHERE tableA.CATEGORY_id = tableAClone.CATEGORY_id
        )
      WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT tableAClone.SECTION_ID
              FROM table2 
              WHERE tableA.CATEGORY_id = tableAClone.CATEGORY_id
        )
      ;
```

Comment: i am getting below error

Error at Command Line:34 Column:32
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action: